# why lost some data after nodetool cleanup in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

We added a new node to datacenter and then run `nodetool cleanup` according to [Add new node to existing cluster in cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html).  But after cleanup completed, we noticed that we lost some data.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please add a bit more info to this question, for example the output of `nodetool status` before and after you added the new node and also how you derived you lost data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's important to understand that `nodetool cleanup` is a potentially ***destructive*** tool.  Your cluster needs to be in a fully-repaired state (from regular, successful runs of `nodetool repair` prior).

When you add a new node to the cluster, the token ranges that each node is responsible for are adjusted, and lowered per node.  This leaves data on the original nodes that they are no longer responsible for.  And that is *by design*.

The idea was that if for whatever reason the node add process failed and you had to leave your cluster at its original size, then the data is still there.  But if you can't guarantee that your cluster was in a fully-repaired state in the first place and cleanup was run, it's possible that not all replicas would have made it to their proper nodes.  But like `nodetool getendpoints` the bootstrap process would have assumed that it was.

That's why it's important to ensure that you have been regularly running `nodetool repair` on your cluster *before* running `nodetool cleanup`.

Comment: I agree that `nodetool repair` should be run regularly, this is very important as you correctly point out. However `nodetool cleanup` will only purge ranges the node does not own. So would it not be more accurate to say that once you have bootstrapped you can't really repair after the fact as those ranges on the existing nodes have been disowned effectively?

Comment: @markc As long as one replica survives and makes it into a valid range on a node, the repair (after bootstrap) should help.  That way the replicas that were missed *should* be streamed.  But if all replicas for a range are corrupted or not in an owned range, then you're right in that repair after bootstrap really won't do much.

Answer (score 1):

`nodetool cleanup` frees partition keys no longer belonging to a node, so after adding a node and transferring it's portion of data, this "portion" is no longer belongs to the old node, so running cleanup will free some space on this node.

If you see that old node now have lower storage, it is ok, there wasn't any data loss.

On other hand, if you really can't find some data, it can be due to data corruption or deleted data (with tombstones). What do you mean by data loss anyway?